# create a new array and push into it in one line - Javascript OOP

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've this code with a function, wherein a I'm trying to define an `array` then on the next line pushing to it:

```
function Spot(value) {
  this.x = null;
  this.y = null;
  this.values = [];
  this.values.push(value);
}
```

I've tried this:

```
this.values = [].push(value);
```

and

```
this.values = (this.values || []).push(value);
```

But failed. Is there something wrong with the code.....

Comment: What has failed? What error do you get?

Comment: `this.values = [ value ]`

Comment: I don't get array made on console screen

Comment: damn, how couldn't I just open up my brain a little -- thanks @freedomn-m

Comment: Since you are not returning anything, you need to call it as a constructor `var spot = new Spot();`

Comment: this.values = new Array(value) ?

Comment: @RohitAgrawal depends on what `this` is - with just the code provided, `this` would be `window`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing the array-initialisation syntax:

```
var x = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
```

in your case, this would be:

```
this.values = [ value ];
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

---

The code:

```
var x = ([]).push("y");
```

looks like it should generate an array and push the value to it.  It does create the array, however the array is not returned to `x`, the new length of the array is returned, ie `1`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and **returns the new length of the array**.  [emphasis mine]

---

As noted in the comments, an alternative that is closer to your original attempt would be:

```
var x = ([]).concat("y");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

> The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead **returns a new array**.

Comment: my bad not to have it figured out on my own.... but still why `(this.values || []).push(value);` did not create an array....?

Comment: Use `concat()` instead of `push()`: `this.values = (this.values || []).concat(value);`.

Answer (score 2):

Just take the value in an array.

```js
function Spot(value) {
    this.x = null;
    this.y = null;
    this.values = [value];
}

var point = new Spot('foo')

console.log(point);
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you are creating the array and pushing `value` to it is correct. But since it is created inside the function you need to access `this` object outside the function in some way.

Since you are not returning anything, you can call it as a constructor.

```
var spot = new Spot()
function Spot(value) {
  this.x = null;
  this.y = null;
  this.values = [];
  this.values.push(value);
}

var spot = new Spot();
```

If you do not want to call it as a constructor than you can simply return `this` object.

```
function Spot(value) {
  this.x = null;
  this.y = null;
  this.values = [];
  this.values.push(value);
  return this;
}
```

Comment: While useful side information, you might want to add a note that this is additional information as it does not answer the question of how to change the array init and population from 2 lines into a single line.

Comment: @freedomn-m, thank you for your suggestion. I have updated my answer.